# Joining number with a slash SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Got a query that when I try and run it it returns Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '0003/' to data type int.

Query is

```
SELECT

name,
date,
CAST(('0' + Location + '/' + ID) AS nvarchar(50)) AS [UniqNumber]

FROM
Table
```

Upon this it returns Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '0003/' to data type int. Location and ID are both ints.

Comment: You are converting a varchar into int. Fine as long as you do not have those special characters/string in it... I take my comment back. Why don't you just `replace`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast the inputs.

```
'0' + CAST(Location AS VARCHAR(20)) + '/' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(20))
```

`int` has higher data type precedence than the string datatypes. If you do `string + int` it will try and cast the string to an integer and add it rather than casting the integer to a string and concatenating it.

Comment: OP wants to get his final output as an `int` isn't it? :)

Comment: @bonCodigo - I doubt that interpretation. Would seem very odd that they are concatenating `/` if that's what they want.

Comment: Thanks. I thought he wants to replace the slash with 0 while concat-ing the two variables together as an `int`. So that's why I replaced the / in Location with 0 and concat it to ID then CAST to int. My first impression is wrong then

Answer (score 0):

Try this as you want to convert `nvarchar` into `int`

```
CAST(REPLACE(Location,'/',0) AS nvarchar(50)) + CAST(ID as nvarchar(50)) AS [UniqNumber]
```

output:

```
0030
```